# Restrict access to AllPosts.aspx

Tags: blog

I created a list called "Posts" and a search scope to only search within that list. However, it seems to also pick up the AllPosts.aspx page, which I dont want people to have access to. Any way I can restrict this access or remove it from the scope?

Comment: Are you using default content type item for list items?

Comment: Yes, its the blog site template and the Posts content type.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Posts Content Type, I assume all the items in list Posts will be derived this content type. Hence please try the following solution:

- Create a Rule in your search scope
- Exclude::PropertyName:ContentType and value Posts

so now your scope must bring back only those results which are from this content type and those are only items not AllPosts.aspx page.